# elasticsearch remote client to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I keep getting this error:

```
 org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
```

My elasticsearch is on AWS Ubuntu Linux.

My TransportClient is wrapped like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public ClientTransport(){


        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "store_cluster").build();
        this.client = new TransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xx.xx.xx.xx", 9300));
    }
```

my test class:

```
ClientTransport c = new ClientTransport();
        CreateIndexResponse create = c.client.admin().indices()
                .create(new CreateIndexRequest("logstash-2015.06.04")).actionGet();
        if (!create.isAcknowledged()) {
            System.out.println("failed to create index: " + indexName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Index created. Index Name: " + indexName);
        }

        c.client.close();
```

I see a lot of discussion on this, but I dont get the solution?

Here is elasticsearch.yml. These are the only configs in my file:

```
network.host: localhost
cluster.name: store_cluster
node.name: store_node
```

Comment: Have you verified that the machine connecting to `xx.xx.xx.xx:9300` can actually _see_ the server and port? In other words, did you open up port 9300 on the AWS machine at `xx.xx.xx.xx` so that the client machine could connect to it? Also, verify your cluster name is correct. Finally, you can check the logs on the ES node. If it doesn't show any connection attempts, then they're most likely being blocked by the firewall.

Comment: I loaded my java app onto the linux machine to be sure. Still getting the same error. Ports are open and all. So even when I run locally it fails.

Comment: Then can you add your settings for your ES node? Can you also show check its logs for the relevant time period (try to connect, then see if any errors appear on the server side of ES)?

Comment: running: sudo ufw status shows "status: inactive" on the firewall.

Comment: Try the logs for ES itself rather than the firewall.

Comment: I have cluster.name =store_cluster, node.name ="store", node.master = false, node.data=false

Comment: You're trying to connect to a cluster above named just `"store"` rather than `"store_cluster"`.

Comment: seems Im running ES 1.4.4 on the server but 1.5.2 in my java.

Comment: Doesnt matter when I use the correct names for cluster and node.

Comment: Can you just add your full settings for your server -- with anything you set in the file -- to the question?

Comment: I just added the file settings. keep in mind I tried 127.0.0.1, etc...

Comment: Unset the `network.host` setting and try to connect with those same settings.

Comment: You may need the AWS plugin (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws), configured via elasticsearch.yml, as well as appropriate IAM policy permissions. In the end, we just went with the REST API for our use case.